# Characterizing a certain set of matrices arising from binary trees

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

Suppose I have a binary tree, like

```
v1           v4
  \         /
   --------
  /         \
v2            v3
```

I can write a matrix for this tree whose $(i,j)$th entry gives the distance between vertex $i$ and $j$. In this case we would have:

$$A =\left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
0&2& 3 &3 \\
2& 0 &3&3\\
3& 3 & 0 &2\\
3&3&2&0
\end{array} \right)$$

These matrices have some nice properties, for instance:

- If you compute $\sum 2^{1-i}$ where the $i$ range over all the nonzero entries in a row, you get $1$
- They are symmetric, with zeroes on the diagonal
- Given such a matrix you can recover the original tree.

My  questions are as follows:

These seem like fairly natural structures to consider. Do they have a name? Can you point me to any reference about them?

I most of all would like to be able to characterize all matrices which arise in this way, but really any information would be a help.

**Edit**: I'm not sure if this is going to be helpful, but I'll attempt to explain what I'm doing in an attempt to shed light on what I mean when I say "characterize". I'm working on a larger problem, involving two binary trees $S$ and $T$ (of the same size) together with an function  $\sigma: leaves(S) \to leaves(T)$.

There is some quantity $f(S;T;\sigma)$ which depends on $\sigma$, and can be easily estimated by knowing these matrices. The goal is to prove that $f(S;S;id)$ bounds $f(S;T;\sigma)$ for any tree $T$, map $\sigma$.

It may be that this is just a dream and the simplest characterization is just "try to reconstruct the tree and see if you fail" but it would be really helpful to have something like "$A$ works if and only if it satisfies all equations of the form $g_n$" (note that this is just an example, and I'd really be happy with anything "clean")

Sorry if this is all quite nebulous.

Comment: This matrix can be found using [min-plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication) multiplication on the adjacency matrix, and then taking a submatrix of just the four vertices you want.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. That article lead me to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix) about the distance matrix, which appears to be what I'm describing.

Comment: (though lest anyone read this and be discouraged from answering, the characterization question still stands)

Comment: What do you mean by "characterize" all matrices which arise in this way?

Comment: Your diagram doesn't look like a binary tree. It could be converted into a binary tree by inserting three non-leaf nodes, but if this is done symmetrically then the distances between leaf nodes would be $2$ and $4$. What is the actual tree structure?

Comment: The condition is that each internal node has exactly three edges. I guess it's more of an "unrooted binary tree"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've seen a name of this type of matrix, other than "tree distance matrix" (which would be a special case of graph distance matrices).

Characterization depends on what kind of criteria you might be looking for. For example, a trivial way of characterizing them is by their one-to-one relation with unrooted binary trees, but this is trivial. However, this means generating all such matrices is equivalent to generating all unrooted binary trees.

A converse characterization could be a simple set of rules to check if a matrix $D=[d_{ij}]$ is a tree distance matrix. One way to do this is as follows.

1. Verify that it is symmetric, has zero on the diagonal, but with all other values integers $\ge2$.
2. Pick a cell, $(i,j)$ with $i\not=j$, with distance value 2: i.e. $d_{ij}=2$. Then, it is required that for all $r$ different from $i$ and $j$, $d_{ir}=d_{jr}$. Now, make a new matrix $D'$ where rows/columns $i$ and $j$ have been replaced with a row/column $k$ and $d'_{kr}=d_{ir}$, $d'_{kk}=0$: i.e. merge rows/columns $i$ and $j$, reducing all off-diagonal values by 1. Again, we should have $d'_{kr}\ge2$ for $r\not=k$.
3. Repeat step 2 on the reduced matrix ($D'$) until either it has been reduced to the $1\times1$ matrix $[0]$, in which case the original matrix was a tree distance matrix, or till there are no more cells $d_{ij}=2$ for which rule 2 may be applied, in which case it was not a tree distance matrix.

If this is good enough to fit what you'd consider a characterization of tree distance matrices, I suppose would depend on what the characterization is to be used for.

---

As you have noted, for any row/column $i$, the sum $\sum_{j\not=i}2^{-d_{ij}}=1/2$. Unfortunately, this is not a sufficient restriction. Two counter-examples are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-&3&3&3&3\\
3&-&3&3&3\\
3&3&-&3&3\\
3&3&3&-&3\\
3&3&3&3&-\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
-&2&4&4&5&6&6&4\\
2&-&4&4&5&6&4&6\\
4&4&-&2&5&4&6&6\\
4&4&2&-&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&-&2&4&4\\
6&6&4&5&2&-&4&4\\
6&4&6&5&4&4&-&2\\
4&6&6&5&4&4&2&-\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I suppose there might be other simple counter-examples as well.

There's another criterion that a tree distance matrix has to satisfy. For any four distinct leaves, $i,j,k,l$, of the four sums
$$
(ij|kl)=d_{ij}+d_{kl},\,
(ik|jl)=d_{ik}+d_{jl},\,
(il|jk)=d_{il}+d_{jk},
$$
two of them must be identical while the third one is smaller than the two others: e.g.
$$
(ij|kl)<(ik|jl)=(il|jk).
$$
However, I don't think this is enough: it should be enough to give you a tree structure with weighted edges, but you'd need some extra criterion to ensure the edges all have weight 1.

Comment: I know that the matrices can be used to reconstruct the original trees. If it's at all possible I'd like to avoid resorting to this reconstruction though. It would be ideal to have a condition which is somehow `local', or at least easy to express in terms of the numerology of the matrix itself.  Something like my first bullet would be nice.